# howto setup dokuwiki parallel to owncloud

Tags: nginx, wiki, dokuwiki

How can I get a working owncloud server with a working dokuwiki? The dokuwiki entries should not be destroyed...

On a raspberry pi an owncloud installation was made following this [article](http://raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/33-raspberry-pi-owncloud) (nginx php5-fpm php5-sqlite php5-gd installed; owncloud.vhost created and linked; owncloud extracted -> /etc/www -> chmod www-data; nginx service started; reboot). However, we did a dokuwiki installation using a [howto](http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-tut-dokuwiki)(german) with these steps:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 
wget http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-stable.tgz
tar xfz dokuwiki-stable.tgz
sudo mv dokuwiki-2014-09-29b /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/dokuwiki-2014-09-29b
```

After that we followed the instructions of

```
http://IP_OF_PI/dokuwiki/install.php
```

As far as I remember, there were failures in the `sudo apt-get install`. However, those were at points were services had to be restarted. We did this afterwards by rebooting the raspberry pi.

Now we are able to use our dokuwiki, but not our owncloud. However, before rebooting we were able to access owncloud with `https://IP_OF_PI/owncloud`. I never got it to sync with other clients so far, but upload of files and access with a browser on other machines was possible.

When we do a (necessary for installation of owncloud)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

the output is

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
nginx.
```

The output of

```
raspberry ~ $ apache2ctl -S
```

is

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

I do not understand what the dokuwiki installation changed so that the nginx is not startable/restartable anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not understand what nginx (s. Wikipedia) is nor its [differences to apache](https://anturis.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache/). However, I mixed nginx and apache. These might get in the way of each other. I decided to use apache2. After I have followed [this post](http://hallard.me/enable-ssl-for-apache-server-in-5-minutes/) I can again access owncloud. In short:

- new certificates in `/etc/apache/ssl` generated,
- `sudo a2enmod ssl`
- `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl`
- In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl` the respective lines
  `SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key` 
  were changed.
- `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`